# What matrix $X$ solves $\max_{X} \|AX\|_F$ s.t. $X^T X=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $X^* = \arg\max_{X} \| A X \|_F^2$ subject to $X^T X=I$. Here $A$ and $X$ are non-square matrices. Specifically $A_{c \times n}$ and $X_{n \times k}$ where $k<c<n$. What would be the solution $X^*$?

I guess $X^*$ would be related to the best rank-$k$ approximation of $A$, like filling columns of $X$ by top $k$ singular vectors of $A$, but I do not know how to go about proving it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Golabi

Comment: Yes, $X$ is comprised of the first $k$ right singular vectors in the singular value decomposition of $A$. There is a proof in Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* (but I haven't the book at hand so that I cannot cite the page number), but you may see the idea in my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2956228) to another question.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in this problem matrix $X$ has orthogonal columns. Hence, using this fact and the fact that Frobenius norm of a matrix is equal to sum of $\ell_2$ norm of its columns, this problem can equivalently be written as the following:
$$\arg\max_{x_1,\dots,x_k} \sum_{i=1}^k x_i^\top A^\top A x_i$$
subject to 
$$x_i^\top x_i = 1 \quad \forall i\in[k], \qquad x_j^\top x_i = 0 \quad \forall i,j\in[k], i\neq j.$$

If $k = 1$, it was easy to see (e.g., by using the Lagrange multipliers) the solution to this problem is to take the largest eigenvector of $A^\top A$ (or equivalently, largest singular vector of $A$). Using Lagrange multipliers for the equivalent problem where $k>1$ shows that your conjecture is correct and the optimal value of $X$ is $k$ largest singualr vectors of $A$.